# Joining two queries to one table and substracting values

Tags: sql, join, pivot

i need to put those two output values  (`Add_sum` and `Minus_sum`) to one table and subtract them (`Add_sum - Minus_sum`) and show this value.

I tried many other options, subqueries etc but could not get it to work.

Query 1:

```
SELECT        I.ItemCode, COUNT(H.TransactionTypeID) AS ADD_Sum
FROM            inMoveHd AS H INNER JOIN
                         inMoveLn AS L ON L.InvMoveID = H.InvMoveID INNER JOIN
                         inItem AS I ON I.ItemID = L.ItemID INNER JOIN
                         inTransactionType AS T ON H.TransactionTypeID = T.TransactionTypeID
WHERE        (T.TransactionSign = 1)
GROUP BY I.ItemCode
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT        I.ItemCode, COUNT(H.TransactionTypeID) AS Minus_Sum
FROM            inMoveHd AS H INNER JOIN
                         inMoveLn AS L ON L.InvMoveID = H.InvMoveID INNER JOIN
                         inItem AS I ON I.ItemID = L.ItemID INNER JOIN
                         inTransactionType AS T ON H.TransactionTypeID = T.TransactionTypeID
WHERE        (T.TransactionSign = -1)
GROUP BY I.ItemCode
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: I hope its better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT  I.ItemCode,
        COUNT(case when T.TransactionSign = 1 then H.TransactionTypeID end) AS ADD_Sum,
        COUNT(case when T.TransactionSign = -1 then H.TransactionTypeID end) AS Minus_Sum
FROM      inMoveHd AS H INNER JOIN
                   inMoveLn AS L ON L.InvMoveID = H.InvMoveID INNER JOIN
                   inItem AS I ON I.ItemID = L.ItemID INNER JOIN
                   inTransactionType AS T ON H.TransactionTypeID = T.TransactionTypeID
WHERE  (T.TransactionSign = -1 or T.TransactionSign = 1)
GROUP BY I.ItemCode
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT        
    I.ItemCode, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionSign = 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Add_Sum,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionSign = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Minus_Sum,
    SUM(T.TransactionSign) difference
FROM 
    inMoveHd AS H INNER JOIN
    inMoveLn AS L ON L.InvMoveID = H.InvMoveID INNER JOIN
    inItem AS I ON I.ItemID = L.ItemID INNER JOIN
    inTransactionType AS T ON H.TransactionTypeID = T.TransactionTypeID
WHERE  T.TransactionSign IN (-1, 1)
GROUP BY I.ItemCode
```